# c# Livechart - How to fix Labeler with DateTime (Winforms)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, livecharts

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now...

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 with .NET 4.7.2 as my Target Framework.

The problem is the x axis (DateTime) keeps outputting to "Monday, January 1, 0001 12:00:00 AM". I've tried so many variations and have researched all over the web, can't seem to put 2 and 2 together.

Please, any help or guidance to the right direction would be very much appreaciated. I might also add that I'm new to c# and .NET.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using LiveCharts;
using LiveCharts.Defaults;
using LiveCharts.Wpf;

namespace FurnTempTen
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private ChartValues<DateTimePoint> GetData()
        {
            var values = new ChartValues<DateTimePoint>();
            values.Add(new DateTimePoint(new DateTime(2023, 1, 1,12,00,00), .285));
            values.Add(new DateTimePoint(new DateTime(2023, 1, 1,13,00,00), .478));
            values.Add(new DateTimePoint(new DateTime(2023, 1, 1,13,30,00), .366));
            values.Add(new DateTimePoint(new DateTime(2023, 1, 2,14,00,00), .228));
            values.Add(new DateTimePoint(new DateTime(2023, 1, 2,14,30,00), .629));
            values.Add(new DateTimePoint(new DateTime(2023, 1, 2,14,30,00), .808));
            values.Add(new DateTimePoint(new DateTime(2023, 1, 2,15,00,00), 1.031));
            values.Add(new DateTimePoint(new DateTime(2023, 1, 2,17,30,00), 1.110));
            return values;
        }
        private void SetAxisLimits(System.DateTime now)
        {
            cartesianChart1.AxisX[0].MaxValue = now.Ticks + TimeSpan.FromHours(4).Ticks;
            cartesianChart1.AxisX[0].MinValue = now.Ticks - TimeSpan.FromHours(4).Ticks;
        }
        private void btnExecute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                cartesianChart1.Series = new SeriesCollection()
                {
                new LineSeries
                {
                    Values = GetData(),
                    PointGeometry = null,
                    StrokeThickness = 2,
                    LineSmoothness = 1,
                }
                };

                cartesianChart1.AxisX.Add(new Axis
                {
                    Title = "Date",
                    DisableAnimations = true,
                    LabelFormatter = value =>
                    {
                        DateTime dateTime = new DateTime((long)value);
                        return dateTime.ToString("F");
                    }
                    //Separator = new Separator { Step = TimeSpan.FromHours(1).Ticks }

                });
                dataGridView1.DataSource = GetData();
                cartesianChart1.LegendLocation = LegendLocation.Right;
                cartesianChart1.Hoverable = false;
                cartesianChart1.DefaultLegend.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                cartesianChart1.Visible = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

This is what I keep getting
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFyCM.png)

I have 'Separator' property commented out because I get the exception below, which I also need some guidance with.

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Ticks must be between DateTime.MinValue.Ticks and DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks.
Parameter name: ticks'

Thank you in advance.